# Status returned after trying to read a namelist is not what would be expected

Tags: fortran

I want to read a namelist from a file but implementing a catch option in the case where the namelist is absent. From what I read in [here](http://msg.ucsf.edu/local/programs/IBM_Compilers/Fortran/html/pgs/lr76.htm) I would expect a status of either 84 or 85. My code then looks something like this:

```
mystat = 0
read( unit = file_unit, nml = lionml, iostat = mystat )

print*, mystat

if ( (mystat == 84) .or. (mystat == 85) ) then
!  (no namelist found? Go on, no big deal...)
else
!  (other stat problems? This may be problematic...)
end if
```

However, this is not the case. The file being read does not have the namelist lionml, but the status returned by the read directive is -1 (EOF) instead of 84/85.

Am I interpreting something wrong from the cited source? I don't understand in which other case I would get stat of 84/85...

Comment: Are you using xlf?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Fortran, but it would seem that EOF would superseded an error in the file.  Why not add another .or. for -1.

Comment: Just to expand slightly on francescalus' comment the positive error codes are compiler dependent. If you are not using IBM's compiler, the numbers almost certainly will be different

Comment: No, I was using gfortran; I don't really know what xlf is, is it IBM's compiler? I didn't know that page's information only referred to that. I would not have thought error information on an intrinsic procedure would be compiler dependent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are in the area of so-called *processor/compiler dependent behaviour*.  There are certain aspects of Fortran where, within certain constraints, the standard does not completely specify the result of even a valid progam.

Here, we have (Fortran 2008, 9.11.5):

> Execution of an input/output statement containing the IOSTAT= specifier causes the scalar-int-variable in the IOSTAT= specifier to become defined with
>
> - a zero value if neither an error condition, an end-of-file condition, nor an end-of-record condition occurs,
> - the processor-dependent positive integer value of the constant IOSTAT_INQUIRE_INTERNAL_UNIT from the intrinsic module ISO_FORTRAN_ENV (13.8.2) if a unit number in an INQUIRE statement identifies an internal file,
> - a processor-dependent positive integer value different from IOSTAT_INQUIRE_INTERNAL_UNIT if any other error condition occurs,
> - the processor-dependent negative integer value of the constant IOSTAT_END (13.8.2.13) if an end-of-file condition occurs and no error condition occurs, or
> - the processor-dependent negative integer value of the constant IOSTAT_EOR (13.8.2.14) if an end-of-record condition occurs and no error condition or end-of-file condition occurs.

The documentation you quote is specific to the implementation by IBM (even that version) and does not (necessarily) apply to the compiler you use.  So, IBM may choose to use `84` for a given error condition, where NAG or Intel (etc) may choose another.

Further, it is not specified by the Fortran standard what counts as an "error condition". From the standard (F2008, 9.11.1)

> The set of input/output error conditions is processor dependent

although so-called *end-of-record* and *end-of-file* conditions (which are not errors) are defined.  Whether the namelist input file missing the namelist counts as an error (and which error) is not specified by the current standard.

Note also that the value for `mystat` from the program of the question when an end-of-file condition occurs isn't necessarily `-1`.  As noted above the negative value `IOSTAT_END` from the intrinsic module `ISO_FORTRAN_ENV` may portably (for a F2008 compiler) be used for comparison in this case.

Comment: What were the iostat rules for F90 / F95? I think we are currently using either F90, F95 or at most F2003 (I have the memory of trying to invoke the ISO_FORTRAN_ENV and receiving complains from the compiler). I once tried downloading the F90 or F95 standards (actually, you were the one who recommended me to check them out) but couldn't find them (the gnu wiki page has those pdf links broken =S and can't seem to find it anywhere else).

Comment: The meaning of status specifier isn't substantively different in F90.  Naturally, the older standards don't mention the intrinsic module's named constant but the processor dependent nature and sign are the same.

Comment: The lines between F90, F95, F2003, F2008, F2018 compiler are somewhat blurred.  You'll be using the subset of the most recent standard implemented by your compiler vendor at the time of release more than a true compiler of one standard.   On the standard documents, I've submitted an edit to the wiki for [tag:fortran].