# Fortran inquire return internal file

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have a situation unexpected with my fortran program.
I want to drop some data in a text file. For some reasons, I created a type to deal with this file.

Therefore, I open a file with the commands (where `f` is my file type object):

```
open(newunit    = f%unit,          &
     file       = trim(adjustl(f%name)), &
     form       = 'FORMATTED',      & 
     access     = 'STREAM',         & 
     action     = 'WRITE',          &
     status     = 'REPLACE',        &
     iostat     = ios)
if(ios /= 0) print '("Problem creating file")', trim(f%name)
```

Then I write stuff like this:

```
write(unit=f%unit,fmt='(100A)') "#Header"
```

And when it is done, I want to close the file. To do this, I call the subroutine:

```
subroutine close_file_ascii(f)    
  implicit none
  class(my_file_type) intent(in) :: f
  logical :: file_opened, file_exist
  integer :: ios

  inquire(unit=f%unit, exist=file_exist, opened=file_opened) !, iostat=ios)
  print *,'file_exist:', file_exist, 'file_opened:', file_opened, 'ios:', ios
  if ((file_opened) .and. (file_exist)) then
     close(unit=f%unit)
  else
    print *,"[WARNING]"
  end if
end subroutine close_file_ascii
```

My problem is in this last subroutine. When I run the program on windows, I get the following error:

```
Fortran runtime error: Inquire statement identifies an internal file
Error termination. Backtrace
```

Therefore, I tried to create MWE to understand the problem, but all of them where working well. So couldn't really isolate the problem. Also a strange thing is that when I compile and execute with `gfortran` on my linux there is no problem, but when I do so on my windows I get the previous error. ( I compile on windows with `gfortran` version 7.3.0 x86_64-posix-sjlj-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 )

I already work-around this problem by uncommenting the end of inquire line in the close subroutine, and everything seems to work fine. And I get the following print:

```
file_exist: T file_opened: T ios:        5018
```

But I would to understand what is going on. So what could create such internal file error (while the file should not be internal but external)? Is my workaround could be harmful ? Is it a bug ? Is there a better way to close safely an opened file? Any ideas to isolate the problem ?

#### EDIT

From roygvib's comment, the following test seems to replicate the problem:

```
program bug
  implicit none
  integer          :: i
  character(len=1) :: s
  write (s,'(i1)') 0
  open(newUnit=i,file='bug.txt',status='unknown')
  inquire(unit=i)
end program bug
```

Comment: What happens if you change the subroutine to take an integer as input and call it as `call close_file_ascii(f%unit)`.  Also, where and how is `my_file_type` defined?

Comment: In a small test it works, in the big program I can't try because there is a procedure pointer that can have it as a target. `my_file_type` is defined before, the first open; with unit and name internal variable. (I know it's painful when there is no MWE...)

Comment: Can't help you if you're unwilling to provide the definition of `my_file_type` or if it is defined in a module along with the `close_file_ascii` subprogram.  You do realize that `ios=5018` signals an error, so no your work-around isn't working fine.

Comment: Potentially a bug of gfortran? (if you have used internal file I/O before?) https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=84412 (which says "Known to fail: 7.3.0 8.0")

Comment: @roygvib, no I have not used internal file I/O before. And when I test the program given in your link I get the same error message. Therefore, if I understand, it is a bug. Right ?

Comment: @evets Yes I realise that this signal is an error, this is why I came here.

Comment: @R.N With gfortran-8.2 on my mac, the test program in the link gives no error. To check potential bug of compilers, it may be useful to try your code with other compilers (if available, e.g. ifort, NAG, etc...) with check options or with latest gfortran >=8.2 etc. (I guess the reason why the code works on Linux might be due to an older version of gfortran w/o regression.)

Comment: RE "ios: 5018", is this simply a garbage value of an undefined local variable (if the inquire line is commented out)?

Comment: @roygvib, "ios: 5018" is the result of the command: `inquire(unit=f%unit, exist=file_exist, opened=file_opened, iostat=ios)`, it is a defined variable. 
I tried on linux with ifort and it runs without errors.

Comment: @roygvib, 5018 is not random garbage.  It has a well-defined meaning.

Comment: I see... It does look like a named constant (iostat_inquire_internal_unit in iso_fortran_env http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/iso_fortran_env https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49078392/status-returned-after-trying-to-read-a-namelist-is-not-what-would-be-expected ) That constant is also 5018 on my mac with gfortran-8.2. So the error number is consistent with the error message...

Comment: Overall, I think it would be great if you can create a reproducible shorter code example somehow (though it may be difficult...) so that, in case it is an unknown compiler bug, it can be reported to bugzilla or compl.lang.fortran etc. (I think this would also be helpful to identify a potential bug on the programmer's side (if any, though not sure atm)).

Comment: 5018 is not a valid unit number in this context. Internal files are NOT being used - what is used is NEWUNIT= which the standard says always returns a negative unit number.

Comment: I think that the code given in the roygvib's comment replicates correctly the problem. So I edit my question. Moreover, I test this short code with a `pgfortran` (PGI) compiler on windows, and it runs perfectly just as with `ifort` 18 and `gfortran` 7.3.0 on Linux ; while the crashs on windows with MinGW's `gfortran`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The update to gfortran 8.1 solved the problem.